# Ignore and continue on specific Symfony2 kernel.exception event

Tags: php, symfony

Scenario:

The Symfony2 project works with main database and a secondary (remote) for remote data. The remote database can be down or the connection between them might be severed. In such case I still want the execution to continue as normal albeit with a notice that the remote is down.

I have so far tried this in my event listener:

```
public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
{
    $exception = $event->getException();

    if (
        $exception instanceof ConnectionException ||
        $exception instanceof PDOException ||
        $exception instanceof \PDOException ||
        $exception instanceof DBALException
    ) {
        $this->flash->flashMessage('remote_server_connection_error', array(), FlashBagUtil::TYPE_ALERT);

//            $kernel   = $event->getKernel();
//            $request  = $event->getRequest();
//            $response = $kernel->handle($request, HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST, true);
//            $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_OK);
//            $event->setResponse($response);

        $event->stopPropagation();
        echo 'works';
    }
}
```

If I uncomment the response part, I get the page retuned as expected but with a status 500, not 200 as I've explicitly set. "works" gets echoed so event part is working fine.

What's the correct way of dealing with an exception and ignoring it for the rest of the request from within Symfony2 kernel.exception listener?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the **[documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#kernel-kernel-exception)**, for `kernel.exception` event :

> As Symfony ensures that the Response status code is set to the most appropriate one depending on the exception, setting the status on the response won't work. If you want to overwrite the status code (which you should not without a good reason), set the X-Status-Code header

So you will have to set this header :

```
$response->headers->set('X-Status-Code', Response::HTTP_OK);
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved my status code issue, but would you say my overall approach is correct?

Comment: In your case, if failing to connect to the remote database does not disturb user's application usage, I would say it is the cleanest way to do this, and a 200 status code is indeed ok in that case.